# Reprojecting all geometries in PostGIS table?

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system

I created a spatial table with SRID:4326. Now I want to change total projection to SRID:32644 into a new table. The old table should remain unchanged.

Comment: I'm adding this as a comment instead of an answer because there should be a more elegant method. But you could copy the table, and then run:
UPDATE <table> SET the_geom=ST_Transform(the_geom,32644);
(Assuming you have the complete entry in your spatial_ref_sys for 32644.)

Comment: i tried but igot this error                                update abc SET geom=ST_Transform(geom,32644);
  new row for relation "abc" violates check constraint "enforce_srid_geom"

Comment: drop that constraint. and its fixed

Answer (score 84, accepted):

If you're on PostGIS 2.0+, you can go:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable 
  ALTER COLUMN geom 
  TYPE Geometry(Point, 32644) 
  USING ST_Transform(geom, 32644);
```

Comment: Noting of course that you should replace "Point" with the actual geometry type of your geometry.

Comment: Is there a simple way to replace `Point` with `The same geometry type as it was`?

Comment: No, afraid not.

Comment: Does this play well with existing indexes?  I.e. if I have an index on column geom whilst it was in 4326, and then I transform to 32644 with this method, does my existing index need to be recreated?

Answer (score 21):

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS 
  SELECT ST_Transform(the_geom,32644) AS the_geom 
  FROM original_table;
```

There should be an integer ID field in your spatial table in order to add it to QGIS.

Comment: I tried as above and succeeded, but I'm unable to export the resultant table into qgis/udig even it's appearing in database?

Comment: What is your exact problem?

Comment: If you are using a version of PostGIS older than version 2.0 you'll need to add a record to your Geometry_Columns table pointing to your new table.

Answer (score 3):

follow this way:

1. `CREATE TABLE 'new_table' AS SELECT * FROM 'old_table';`
2. `ALTER TABLE new_table DROP CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_the_geom;`
3. `ALTER TABLE new_table DROP CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_the_geom;`
4. `UPDATE new_table SET the_geom = ST_SetSRID(the_geom, new_srid);`
5. `ALTER TABLE new_table ADD CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_the_geom CHECK (st_srid(the_geom) = (new_srid));`
6. `ALTER TABLE new_table ADD  CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_geom CHECK ((geometrytype(the_geom) = 'POINT'::text OR the_geom IS NULL);`
7. That is it!

if you cannot create new table in first line pls try 2. and 3. first then create your table with number 1.

i hope it helps you...

Comment: This solution not reproject geometries. If geometries are stored using other SRID, data will be inconsistence after change constrains. You need use st_trasnform.