# SRID 4326 and geometry conversion

Tags: postgis, postgresql, coordinate-system, srid

From this line:

```
SELECT ST_AsEWKT(geom) FROM buildings LIMIT 1;
```

I get this result:

```
"SRID=4326;MULTIPOLYGON(((404269.308014269 4543087.6184561,...)))"
```

I'm wondering if the coordinations are actually in the right format as SRID 4326?

EDIT ---- > 
The table was updated using this line:

```
SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID('buildings','geom',4326);
```

Comment: Very strange. They certanly don't look like 4326. Projected 3857 maybe?

Comment: Actually this table didn't have SRID at all, it was 0, so I Updated to 4326, but seems like it's not properly fixed. any suggestions? thank you

Comment: Hmm, if it didn't have SRID to begin with, im not sure what is the default projection? Maybe you should recreate the table and set srid explicitly! Then reimport the data.

Comment: @Kourosh How did you update it to 4326?

Comment: @R.K, i've updated the question, the query line i made for updating SRID. thank you

Comment: @Kourosh Got it. Btw, why did you decide to set it to 4326 btw?

Comment: @R.K, the reason is, I have some geographical coordinations in degrees, and need but the current SRID obviously is not in degrees and makes life much harder, cause let's say using ST_DWithin, you must know the systems SRID to be able to get the expected result....thank you so much :)

Answer (score 4):

Acording to the following information found at [spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org/), the response is no.

> EPSG:4326
>
> WGS84 Bounds: -180.0000, -90.0000, 180.0000, 90.0000
>
> Projected Bounds: -180.0000, -90.0000, 180.0000, 90.0000
>
> Scope: Horizontal component of 3D system. Used by the GPS satellite navigation system and for NATO military geodetic surveying.
>
> Last Revised: 2007-08-27
>
> Area: World
>
> http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/

Comment: how could I reproject this geom column with proper SRID(e.g 4326) without having to reimport all over again? thanks

Comment: @Kourosh That's already answered http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39138/how-to-reproject-all-geometries-in-a-postgis-table