# osm2pgsql import OSM data in EPSG:27700

Tags: import, epsg, osm2pgsql

I am trying to use `osm2pgsql` on Windows to import OSM data to a PostGIS database. I want to pass the [EPSG:27700](https://epsg.io/27700) via the `--proj` option as follows:

```
osm2pgsql --proj 27700 <other options not shown>
```

However, I get the following error:

```
osm2pgsql version 0.96.0 (64 bit id space)

Osm2pgsql failed due to ERROR: creation of CRS failed: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas as to why this is not working?

I used the Windows binary from [osm2pgsql | History](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/history)

Comment: Have you seen this report [osm2pgsql: Import data in custom projection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78519/osm2pgsql-import-data-in-custom-projection)? Moreover, I agree with what @AndreJ said. "I think it will be much easier for you to import the stuff using lat/long, and do the reprojection afterwards in the database."