# Distance between Polygon and Point

Tags: postgis

I am working on a query to find the closest point between polygon and point

Can I use this operator to calculate the distance:

```
SELECT a.point, b.poly FROM tableA a, tableB b 
WHERE ST_Distance_Sphere( ST_Transform(a.point,4269), ST_Transform(b.poly,4269)) < 50 
ORDER BY a.point<-> b.poly
LIMIT 1;
```

But it run and take a very long time without results or error message.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a question here (no question mark, and not obvious what you need). Can you click edit below the question and update it with details of what you'd like to know?

Comment: Can you please define what you mean by 'closest point between polygone and point'? An Image might help us understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 8):

`ST_Distance_Sphere` is implemented only for points.

I suggest you to use `ST_Distance` instead, which provides the minimum distance between two bi-dimensional geometries of any type.

I've performed a similar test with two tables (point vs polygon), using this code:

```sql
SELECT a.gid point_gid, b.gid polygon_gid, (SELECT ST_Distance(a.geom, b.geom)) distance
    FROM harta_gal_etichete a, harta_gal_parcele b 
    WHERE (SELECT ST_Distance(a.geom, b.geom) < 50)
    ORDER BY a.gid;
```

If you have really big tables (spatial indexed), you'll have to wait a few minutes to obtain  a result like this:

[image]

---

**EDIT**:

Thanks to the comments I was able to reproject my code and to achieve a significant reducing of the (same data set) processing time (from 269 seconds to 10):

```sql
-- Reproject the point table geometry
CREATE TABLE public.harta_gal_etichete_4296 AS 
    SELECT ST_Transform(geom, 4269) AS geom 
    FROM harta_gal_etichete;

-- Reproject the polygon table geometry
CREATE TABLE public.harta_gal_parcele_4296 AS 
    SELECT ST_Transform(geom, 4269) AS geom 
    FROM harta_gal_parcele;

-- Compute the distances between the two geometries
SELECT a.gid point_gid, b.gid polygon_gid, (SELECT ST_Distance(a.geom, b.geom)) distance
    FROM public.harta_gal_etichete_4296 a, public.harta_gal_parcele_4296 b 
    WHERE ST_DWithin(a.geom, b.geom, 50)
    ORDER BY a, b
```

[image]

I choosed this solution because using ST_Transform for 205496 rows last forever.

Full credit goes to ["How to reproject all geometries in a PostGIS table"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39138/how-to-reproject-all-geometries-in-a-postgis-table), [Taber](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/15076/taber) and [Jakub Kania](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/16594/jakub-kania)

Comment: I've always heard than "ST_Dwithin" is faster than "ST_Distance" in this case... Am I wrong?

Comment: I guess you are right! You have a vote from me! Let's hope the user don't want to see the distances!

Comment: You probably should address the most important issue that is indexing, he's using `ST_TRANSFORM`after all.

Comment: but this returns all polygons within 50m of each point. He asks for just the closest.

Answer (score 3):

Try [ST_Within](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0SVN/ST_DWithin.html), it's return a boolean, and it's faster.

Something like:

```
SELECT a.point, b.poly FROM tableA a, tableB b 
WHERE ST_Within( ST_Transform(a.point,4269), ST_Transform(b.poly,4269), 50) 
ORDER BY a.point<-> b.poly
LIMIT 1;
```