# PostGIS reproject data

Tags: postgis, postgresql, coordinate-system

I have an infrastructure layer that is lat/long values and has an SRID of 4269.

I have brought this shapefile into PostGIS to try and reproject the data to 3424 (state plane of NJ)
this is my query to reproject

```
ALTER TABLE infrastructure
   ALTER COLUMN geom 
   TYPE Geometry(Point, 3424) 
   USING ST_Transform(geom, 3424);
```

but it still shows up as lat long values when I do the below query

[image]

I then brought the infrastructure shapefile into qgis and all the hundreds out points showed up in one area outside of NJ...I am not sure what i am doing wrong here

Comment: GeoJSON folks nowadays want that only supported coordinate system in GeoJSON is lon/lat. Perhaps that's the reason. Try some other output format.

Comment: No state plane coords can be returned with the GeoJSON query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are altering the column not the column values I think, try updating the geometry.

```
Update infrastructure set geom= st_transform(geom,3424)
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the ALTER TABLE way, that's how it goes in PostGIS >= 2.0 http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39138/reprojecting-all-geometries-in-postgis-table