# Problem to convert geometry to coordinates of geometry(MultiLineString) data

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgadmin-3

I am stuck converting a  **geometry(MultiLineString)** into coordinates.
The following I did.

1. I download the data from [this Austin Contours data link](https://data.austintexas.gov/Geodata/2003-10-foot-Contours/iju8-kr7s)
2. I import the shape files using PGAdmin III and inserted around 894345 data.
3. In last column I got the following geom MultiLineString.

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

When I converted this into coordinates from online [link](https://rodic.fr/blog/online-conversion-between-geometric-formats/) it gives the wrong coordinated data as given below

> {"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[3094065,10085118.8],[3094033.7199999997,10085119.19],[3094030.33,10085119.28],[3094027.54,10085119.5],[3094025.41,10085119.72],[3094022.75,10085120],[3094019.3899999997,10085121.120000001],[3094016.15,10085121.91],[3094015.8600000003,10085121.94],[3094012.48,10085122.17],[3094008.0300000003,10085122.3],[3094005.63,10085122.17],[3094000.3899999997,10085121.49],[3093999.62,10085121.52],[3093996.19,10085121.84],[3093992.1100000003,10085122.379999999],[3093991.75,10085122.44],[3093987.95,10085123.23],[3093985.9299999997,10085123.72],[3093983.91,10085124.08],[3093982.84,10085124.18],[3093980.81,10085124.24],[3093977.3200000003,10085124.46],[3093974.31,10085125.1],[3093970.3200000003,10085126.19],[3093954.2800000003,10085132.07],[3093950.63,10085133.66],[3093948.8,10085134.64],[3093946.3,10085136.03],[3093943.04,10085137.69],[3093940.2800000003,10085139],[3093938.25,10085139.93],[3093935.01,10085141.2],[3093932.5,10085142.09],[3093929.6799999997,10085142.96],[3093920.4699999997,10085145.6],[3093917.99,10085146.4],[3093915.4,10085147.45],[3093912.73,10085148.61],[3093907.38,10085150.96],[3093905.2199999997,10085151.99],[3093901.42,10085154.36],[3093899.3600000003,10085155.71],[3093898.19,10085156.55]]]}

Which is not the lat long.
I didn't understand why I getting this I am using the following query to get the data from the PostgreSQL database tables.

```
BEGIN 
SELECT row_to_json(fc.*) as dparcel into ac
FROM 
(
  SELECT  'FeatureCollection' AS type, 
    array_to_json(array_agg(f.*)) AS features 
  FROM 
  ( 
    SELECT  'Feature' AS type,  
      ( 
        SELECT  row_to_json(t) as properties  
        FROM 
        ( 
          select * from austin.austin_contours WHERE gid = adp.gid
        ) t 
      ),
    ST_AsGeoJSON(geom)::json  as geometry
    FROM austin.austin_contours  adp
    LIMIT 20
  ) f 
) fc; 
return;
END;
```

Here geom is the column name of austin.austin_contours  table.

Comment: the data is in a projected CRS, the coordinates *meter* (or possibly even *feet*) in relation to the reference axes; do you know the CRS SRID of that data?

Comment: No, I am sorry... I don't know the CRS SRID, because I import the data directly from shapefile via PostGIS Shapefile and DBF Loader.
But yes I import the shape file the import/export manager window default was 0 I just saw that.
I was also wondering the the string is right or not ?

Comment: the string is fine, it just need a SRID, at least to be transformed to the geographic coordinates you seem to want. what tools do you have available? QGIS? or are you familiar with the OGR command line tools (i.e. *ogrinfo*)? the shapefiles should have the CRS info in it´s metadata or go check the providers homepage for info on it.

Comment: I didn't work on QGIS recently, so not so much aware on this and don't have software available with me and not worked on  OGR command line tools yet. I just try to show the shape files on http://mapshaper.org/ and get the other format data as I need.

Comment: I got the CRS from QGIS. CRS is "[+proj=lcc +lat_1=30.11666666666667 +lat_2=31.88333333333333 +lat_0=29.66666666666667 +lon_0=-100.3333333333333 +x_0=699999.9999999999 +y_0=3000000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=us-ft +no_defs]".
Now what need to do, please help me

Comment: I think it's SRID is 2277.
CRS is : NAD83 / Texas Central (ftUS)
PROJ :
Proj4: +proj=lcc +lat_1=31.88333333333333 +lat_2=30.11666666666667 +lat_0=29.66666666666667 +lon_0=-100.3333333333333 +x_0=699999.9998983998 +y_0=3000000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=us-ft +no_defs

Comment: okay, it's hard to tell if you've screwed up your data already (no offense, but CRS's are sensitive...); I'd recommend to reimport with the GUI tool (as you are familiar with it). in the import window, change the SRID to the one you identified and import ([see here](https://connect.boundlessgeo.com/docs/suite/4.8/_images/pgshp_srid.png)). use `SELECT ST_SRID(geom) FROM <your_table>` to verify the SRID. then  run `ALTER TABLE <your_table> ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(MULTILINESTRING, 4326) USING ST_Transform(geom, 4326)` to permanently transform your geometries to WGS84.

Answer (score 0):

According to the `.prj` file included it is stored in `NAD_1983_StatePlane_Texas_Central_FIPS_4203_Feet` which according to epgs.io is [ESRI:102739](http://epsg.io/102739) and probably [EPSG:42307](http://epsg.io/42307).

Comment: ok, but we need CRS SRID of the data I imported which I am not able to get it, I thing we got this we can do something for string and get the right coordinate multiline string data, is that make sense ?

Comment: that is the SRID of your data

Comment: Ok...So EPSG:42307 is the SRID. What I need to do in that to get the right coordinates of the multilinestring data given above.

Comment: I set the SRID to 4326 now from the following query.
ALTER TABLE austin.austin_contours ALTER COLUMN geom SET DATA TYPE geometry(MULTILINESTRING, 4326) USING ST_SetSRID(geom,4326);
Again when I select the data the out of coordinate is same, what to do to get the right data now.

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/209099/postgis-reproject-data