# Operation on mixed SRID geometries error

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry, query, srid

I have two tables `flickr_edin` and `temmpat`.

`temppat` was created using:

```
CREATE TABLE temppat (id serial, geom geometry);
INSERT INTO temppat (geom) VALUES (ST_GeomFromText('POINT (326253.33 674110.63)'));
```

`flickr_edin` contains columns `id`, `date_taken`, `user` and `geom`.

I want to find out how many photos have been taken within 200m of this location in `temmpat` for each day of the week.

This is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count,EXTRACT('dow' FROM date_taken) as dow
FROM flickr_edin a JOIN temppat b ON ST_WITHIN(a.geom,ST_BUFFER(b.geom,200))
GROUP BY dow;
```

I get this error:

> ERROR:  contains: Operation on mixed SRID geometries (Polygon, 0) !=
> (Point, 27700) SQL state: XX000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `SRID` of the table you create. To create it with the same `SRID` as the `flickr_edin` table:

```
CREATE TABLE temppat (id serial, geom geometry(Geometry,27700));
INSERT INTO temppat (geom) VALUES (ST_GeomFromText('POINT (326253.33 674110.63)'));
```

To find out the `SRID`(s) of a table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ST_SRID(geom)) ST_SRID(geom) FROM flickr_edin
```

To set the `SRID` of a geom column that has already been created:

```
UPDATE temppat SET geom = ST_SETSRID(geom,27700)
```

Note that this won't transform the geometries. For that, see [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39138/reprojecting-all-geometries-in-postgis-table)

You can also set the `SRID` on the fly, but it's better to update the table itself if you're dealing with a missing `SRID` for a column. Setting `SRID` on the fly enables you to do spatial operations on two tables that have different `SRID`s. To do it on the fly, using your query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count,EXTRACT('dow' FROM date_taken) as dow
FROM flickr_edin a JOIN temppat b ON ST_WITHIN(a.geom,ST_BUFFER(ST_SETSRID(b.geom,27700),200))
GROUP BY dow;
```

Answer (score 2):

An inline SQL test to demonstrate what goes wrong and how to fix the problem.

```
select ST_Within(
ST_GeomFromText('POINT (326253.33 674110.63)'),
ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT (326253.33 674110.63)',27700),10));

ERROR:  contains: Operation on mixed SRID geometries
(Polygon, 27700) != (Point, 0)
SQL state: XX000


select ST_Within(
ST_GeomFromText('POINT (326253.33 674110.63)',27700),
ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT (326253.33 674110.63)',27700),10));

true
```